# Find week number within range of dates in Perl

Tags: perl, date-manipulation

I have a range of dates -- say 2012-01-30 .. 2012-04-06 -- which denote a set of weeks that fall within these dates.  These weeks are numbered 1 through 10.  Given today's date (for instance, 2012-02-29), I want to be able to get the week number within the range (in this case, 5).  How do I achieve this in Perl?

Comment: Do your weeks start on Monday? Will the date range always start on a Mondaya and end on a Friday?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of the end date doesn't make any difference unless you want to incorporate some value checking. The value that you need is *week(start date) - week(this date) + 1*. I recommend the `Date::Calc` module for its tidiness and efficiency. The code looks like this

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Date::Calc 'Week_Number';

sub week {
  Week_Number(split /-/, $_[0]);
}

print week('2012-02-29') - week('2012-01-30') + 1, "\n";
```

**OUTPUT**

```
5
```

Comment: If it matters to the user, Date::Calc isn't a core module, while Time::Piece has been since v5.9.5

Comment: @JRFerguson: Since I already use `Date::Calc`, it's not really an issue.

Answer (score 3):

Package [`Time::Piece`](https://metacpan.org/module/Time%3a%3aPiece) has [`strptime`](https://metacpan.org/module/Time%3a%3aPiece#Date-Parsing) method to parse string into a time object and `week` method to indicate number of the week of the time object.

```
use Time::Piece;
my @dates = ('2012-01-30', ..., ...., '2012-04-06');

foreach my $strdate (@dates) {
    my $date = Time::Piece->strptime($strdate, "%Y-%m-%d");
    print "Number of week for '$strdate' is " . $date->week . "\n";
}
```

All you need to do is just to count number of unique weeks in your range.

Comment: This is a neat solution, but requires me to expand the array `@dates` and iterate over it, counting unique weeks.  Yes, it works, and doesn't require any non-core modules, but my preference is for a smaller (in terms of code) solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
use DateTime qw();
my (undef, $initial_weeknumber) 
    = DateTime->new(year => 2012, month => 1, day => 30)->week;
my (undef, $target_weeknumber)  
    = DateTime->new(year => 2012, month => 2, day => 29)->week;
printf 'We are in week %d of the Jashank epoch.', 
    1 + $target_weeknumber - $initial_weeknumber;
```